# Difference between $F_X(x)$ and $F(x)$ in probability?

Tags: probability

What is this difference in notation between $F_X(x)$ and $F(x)$? (where $F(x) = P\{X \leq x\}$ Thanks.

Comment: Is "Fx(x)" $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$, i.e. the density? Or is the context $F_X(x)$, which refers to the "cdf corresponding to random variable X"?

Comment: @AlexR. : See my answer below. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $F_X$ specifies which random variable you're taking the c.d.f. of.  That way you can tell the difference between $F_X(6)$ and $F_Y(6)$.  The notation without the subscript should be used only when there is no possible question about that.

Comment: okay perfect thanks